# How to convert a png image created from a list of tuples back to that list of tuples?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

`tupledlist=[(71, 146, 110), (71, 146, 98), (71, 146, 99), (71, 146, 109), (71, 146, 26), (71, 146, 99), (71, 146, 109), (71, 146, 26), (71, 146, 91), (71, 146, 26), (71, 146, 110), (71, 146, 95), (71, 146, 109), (71, 146, 110), (71, 146, 26), (71, 146, 103), (71, 146, 95), (71, 146, 109), (71, 146, 109), (71, 146, 91), (71, 146, 97), (71, 146, 95), (71, 146, 26), (71, 146, 91), (71, 146, 104), (71, 146, 94), (71, 146, 26), (71, 146, 110), (71, 146, 98), (71, 146, 99), (71, 146, 109), (71, 146, 26), (71, 146, 99), (71, 146, 109), (71, 146, 26), (71, 146, 91), (71, 146, 26), (71, 146, 110), (71, 146, 95), (71, 146, 109), (71, 146, 110), (71, 146, 26), (71, 146, 102), (71, 146, 99), (71, 146, 109), (71, 146, 110)]`

```
from PIL import Image
OUTPUT_IMAGE_SIZE = (1280, 720)
for frame_number, color in enumerate(tupledlist):
    image = Image.new('RGB', OUTPUT_IMAGE_SIZE, color=color)
    image.save("path.png")
```

This will create a png image. Now I want the list of tuples from the image back. How to achieve this? I tried i`mage.getbands()` but it's not working .

```
import PIL
from PIL import Image
image=Image.open("c:/users/ashub/desktop/encrypted.png")
image.getbands()
```

Comment: Try `list(image.getdata())`. For more information, take a look [here](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.Image.getdata).

Comment: I tried it but it's not working.

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: I am only getting a list of tuples with only one RGB value example: (71, 146, 110) and this is infinite.

Comment: @Demonking28 This is expected since in the for loop each time you create an images with a single color in all pixels (1280x720) no?

Comment: Yeah,this is true but if i want the list back from the image how should i proceed?

Comment: It's because of the way you initialize and save your image. If I'm right, you will always get `(71, 146, 110)`. Based on the documentation, you need to pass the `tupledlist` itself as an argument in `color`. You don't need the loop. Just create the image and save it.

Comment: @VasilisG. Ok,thanks!

Comment: You can also look at `image.putdata()`

Comment: @VasilisG. But the argument should be a tuple not a list then how can i pass the whole list in one go?

Comment: Convert it to a tuple. You can also look at `image.putdata()`, as @urban mentioned above.

Comment: @VasilisG. I have a list of tuples .It doesn't have a single tuple so for that i will need a for loop.

Comment: Did you try with `putdata()`?

Comment: Yeah I also tried putdata()

Comment: The `for` loop in the first snippet of code is creating 46 different images all named `path.png`. The last one will be all that's left.

Comment: @martineau Yes,I got it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to achieve this:

```
from PIL import Image

tupledlist=[(71, 146, 110), (71, 146, 98), (71, 146, 99), (71, 146, 109), (71, 146, 26), (71, 146, 99), (71, 146, 109), (71, 146, 26), (71, 146, 91), (71, 146, 26), 
            (71, 146, 110), (71, 146, 95), (71, 146, 109), (71, 146, 110), (71, 146, 26), (71, 146, 103), (71, 146, 95), (71, 146, 109), (71, 146, 109), (71, 146, 91), (71, 146, 97), 
            (71, 146, 95), (71, 146, 26), (71, 146, 91), (71, 146, 104), (71, 146, 94), (71, 146, 26), (71, 146, 110), (71, 146, 98), (71, 146, 99), (71, 146, 109), (71, 146, 26), 
            (71, 146, 99), (71, 146, 109), (71, 146, 26), (71, 146, 91), (71, 146, 26), (71, 146, 110), (71, 146, 95), (71, 146, 109), (71, 146, 110), (71, 146, 26), (71, 146, 102), 
            (71, 146, 99), (71, 146, 109), (71, 146, 110)]

OUTPUT_IMAGE_SIZE = (1280, 720)
image = Image.new('RGB', OUTPUT_IMAGE_SIZE)
image.putdata(tupledlist)
image.save("path.png")
print("Saved image.")

image=Image.open("path.png")
print(list(image.getdata()))
```

The list with the RGB values will be stored in the image, but the rest of the pixels remaining will take RGB values (0,0,0). Printing them will show you all of the 921600 (1280x720) pixels.